# Proper way of parallezing functions with non-serializable dependencies with Python Multiprocessing (Pickle Error)?

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I parallelized some Python functions with multiprocessing's parallel map, and it worked well. However, now some of the functions depend on objects that contain native code that can't be serialized (Pickle error).

Notice that all the functions, including the ones with non-serializable dependencies, are highly amenable to parallelization (before this problem, I was simply applying a parallel map), and the only problem is that now some of them need to load in memory objects that can't be serialized.

I imagine some possible workarounds, but all of them seem either non-efficient or cumbersome (in terms of code readability and maintainability) to me:

- Instead of loading once the non-serializable dependencies (I do it in the `__init__()` method, and then make the class callable), load them in every call to the function: inefficient.
- I could create a process specifically for each of the functions with non-serializable dependencies, and then explicitly communicate with them, but losing the convenience of multiprocessing's parallel map.
- Alternatively, perhaps I could maintain these non-serializalbe objects as global variables using multiprocessing's manager... I don't know exactly how.

For clarity, I attach some pseudocode/toy example:

```
class SerializableFunction:
    def __init__(param):
        self.param = param

    def __call__(arg):
       if self.param == 'identity':
           return arg
       return 0

import library  # Python binding for a non-python application

class NonSerializableFunction:
    def __init__(param, path):
        self.param = param
        self.non_serializable_dependency = library.load(path)  # expensive operation, reads from disk and initializes the object

    def __call__(arg):
        if self.param == 'identity':
            return arg
        return self.non_serializable_dependency(arg)  # this call is also expensive
```

Before this problem, I simply composed the functions, and then called the resulting function through a parallel map.

Which would be the proper way of handling this problem? Thanks!

Note: Some of the functions I use are actual functions, and some of them are callable objects. For simplicity, I referred to them just as functions. Anyway, notice that the non-serializability doesn't come from using callable objects, but from loading non-serializable dependencies.